# AngularJS: Pass textbox value to services

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new in angularJS. Currently working on services. I tried to pass text-box value to services. I don't know how to pass. I code but it's not working.

```
app.service("wishService", function ($timeout) {
    this.wishHim = function (_wishMessage) {
        $timeout(function () {
            alert('Hi ,' + _wishMessage);
        }, 2000);
    }
});

app.controller('wishCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, wishService) {    
    $scope.Message = "";
    $scope.SendMessage = function (wishMessage) {
        wishService.wishHim(wishMessage);
    };
}]);


<div ng-controller="wishCtrl">
        Wish Message: <input type="text" ng-model="wishMessage" />
        <input type="button" value="Send Message" ng-click="SendMessage(wishMessage)" /><br />
        Your Message : {{Message}}
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/MVKnXmXTFY4fTvZigPR1?p=preview)**

Comment: here is useful source about how to write code in angular right  https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide I've also made plunker for you https://plnkr.co/edit/UJD7jYPksSjFYjmsWRtj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**wishService** injection problem

```
app.controller('wishCtrl', ['$scope', 'wishService', function ($scope, wishService) {    
    $scope.Message = "";
    $scope.SendMessage = function (wishMessage) {
        wishService.wishHim(wishMessage);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This was, indeed, the main  problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code, see the [PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/hB2a635AEGgLG50BYNDZ?p=preview) here. While what Sandeep said is correct, you also had a TON of other problems. Refer to what I changed.

Edit: It was brought to my attention that what I changed your code to is the format of a factory, rather than a service:

```
app.service("MessageService", function () {

var service = {
  msg: undefined,

  setMsg: function(msg){
    this.msg = msg; 
  },

  getMsg: function(msg){
    return this.msg; 
  }
}

return service;
});
```

Comment: that is the format of a factory. the service in the question is ok actually

Comment: Don't know the difference enough to say anything definitively, they don't seem to make any difference to me. Will change answer to reflect that though, ty.

Comment: well it's confusing to me too, to be honest, so I keep using factories cause they seem more clear to me. one basic difference is that you have to return something with a factory but in a service `this.msg` is sufficient without a return.

Comment: Thanks - that's about as far as I understand it as well.